# Amazon S3 server multiple upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm writing a program that saves images on Amazon S3 servers. My test suite is taking close to a minute to run due to having to run multiple uploads straight to S3 in order to test various features of the photos.

What is the issue here and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1- Use multipart upload to speed it up, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html

2- Use a mock "no-op" class to fake the upload instantly, see https://code.google.com/p/mockito/

3- Use a local emulation for testing, see https://github.com/jubos/fake-s3